# Symfony - composer and parameters.yml

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4

I wonder how should I handle this correctly.

When I run "composer install" on the server it changes parameters.yml and then "git pull" complains that local file is changed.

What I do in that case is I delete remote parameters.yml file and checkout it again.

Surely there must be a better way?

Comment: So you don't want `parameters.yml` to be created/updated by `composer install` ... or do you just want `git pull` to not complain if `parameters.yml` has been updated by `composer install`?

Comment: parameters.yml should never be checked in to source control.  The file is intended for server specific information including things like passwords.  So remove parameters.yml from source code control and then change any sensitive information that might have been checked in.

Comment: @Cerad ok that makes sense. So non-sensitive info goes to the dist file?

Comment: Yes, non-sensitive information can stay in the `parameters.yml.dist` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already stated by @Cerad the `parameters.yml` file should never be checked into your git repository and further be ignored.

1. Remove `parameters.yml` from the repository (including history)

   `git rm --cached app/config/parameters.yml`
2. Ignore the file in your repository

   `echo 'app/config/parameters.yml' | tee -a .gitignore`

Afterwards re-create `parameters.yml` on your server and `git pull` will not complain anymore.

Comment: Thanks, will 1. delete remote history as well?

Comment: In order to update on your server run: `git fetch --all` followed by `git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: @GrumpyHat To answer your implied question about deleting history, just assume that anything you have ever checked will last forever and be publicly accessible.  So change any passwords or secret information that has already been checked in.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent it adding to composer.json:

```
...
"extra": {
    ...
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "keep-outdated": true
    },
    ...
```

Change app/config/parameters.yml with your parameters.yml path

See: https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler#keeping-outdated-parameters

I'm agree with @Cerad, you shuold remove from git repository your parameter.yaml and add to .gitignore

"parameters.yml is not committed to your version control. In fact, the .gitignore file that comes with Symfony prevents it from being committed."

See: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/configuration.html#the-special-parameters-yml-file